# Set up a custom domain and track accesses to it

Tags: privacy, tracking, dns

I would like to know who visits links that are in my mail and chat messages; is there a web app that does the following?

- when I sign up, it gives me one or more unique personalized URLs or domain names such as https://d937a83db313b.examplewebappname.com ;
- logs and reports to me every access to that URL/domain, with source IP, time and possibly also user agent information. (possibly getting information from both DNS and web server logs).